# Issues with conversion of svg element to .svg

Tags: javascript, html, svg, attributes, adobe-illustrator

After hours of looking for a solution here and there, I come here to ask for help.
I'm developing a customization module using `<svg>` element and Javascript.
In the end, I convert and download the SVG element in a `.svg` file but the problem is that some elements like the `<text>` ones are not in the right place when opening the file with Illustrator, it doesn't seem to care about the `x` and `y` attributes.
When I open the file in a browser, everything is in the right place.

Here is the HTML of the downloaded .svg file I get, all at the right place (the browser read the HTML attributes well I guess) : https://codepen.io/florianeychenne/pen/vYRgMWx

Here is the rendering in Illustrator :
[image]

Comment: presumably you need to [report that here](https://www.adobe.com/products/wishform.html)

Comment: Change the zoom in illustrator from 30.28% to 100%.

Comment: @smpa01 The zoom doesn't change the problem here.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'd say the problem comes first from my code.

Answer (score 0):

The browser contains it to the first SVG element, which is width="833" height="396". Thats why you don't see the 'Exemple', it is contained to that first SVG tag. Illustrator does not contain anything, as it is not a browser viewport. I think that if you use only 1 SVG tag, it will solve your issue. It should then render the same in both software.

Comment: Ok little update, I used a VSCode's live server to run the module, that's what added the <script> and mixed everything badly.
Here is the text from the downloaded .svg when ran offline : https://codepen.io/florianeychenne/pen/wvmJrLw
So everything is well contains in the <svg> and the result on Illustrator is still the same...

Comment: What result are you looking for? Your first SVG tag has a width="833" height="396"  so that's the bounding box and that's what the browser will parse as an element. Illustrator doesn't have a box modal like a browser does, so it will show you everything, even if the elements are outside the initial SVG tag. If you don't want to see those elements in Illustrator, than you can use a clipping path or mask to hide them, or simply remove the elements.

Comment: I need to get the exact same result as in the codepen codepen.io/florianeychenne/pen/wvmJrLw
Every elements at the same place that it is in the codepen. In that codepen link, there is no element outside the svg tag.

Comment: @Florian then the easiest is to simply delete the elements in your .svg that are not visible anyway.

Comment: I need those elements thats the thing.

Comment: @Florian I'm confused. You said you want it exactly like it is in the codepen. Those are elements are not in the codepen. If you want to include those elements, they simply need to be positioned inside of the 833x396, or make your main svg element bigger to fit it in.

Answer (score 0):

#### Some ideas for a workaround

- convert/combine all transformations to `matrix()`:
  this way we circumvent problems with `transform-origin` (Illustrator
  apparently can't use it - rotations will have a wrong pivot point)
- convert nested `svg` elements to `<g>` group elements
- some attributes like `textLength` won't work at all in AI - you might use a condensed font instead.

#### Working example

```js
// getTransformToElement polyfill
SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement = SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement || function(
  toElement) {
  return toElement.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(this.getScreenCTM());
};


function fixNestedSvgs() {
  let svgs = document.querySelectorAll('svg');
  let nested = document.querySelectorAll('svg svg');
  // all transformations to matrix()
  svgs.forEach(function(svg) {
    let children = [...svg.children];
    children.forEach(function(child) {
      transFormToMatrix(child);
      styleToAttribute(child, ['fill', 'stroke', 'stroke-width']);
    });
  })
  // nested to groups
  nested.forEach(function(svg) {
    let parent = svg.parentNode.closest('svg');
    nestedSvgToGroup(svg);
    svgMarkup.value = parent.outerHTML;
  })
}


// all transformations to matrix()
function transFormToMatrix(el) {
  let type = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
  let matrixString = '';
  let types = ["path", "polygon", "polyline", "rect", "ellipse", "circle", "line", "text", "g", "svg"];
  if (types.indexOf(type) !== -1) {
    // get el matrix
    let matrix = el.getTransformToElement(el.parentNode.closest("svg"));
    let [a, b, c, d, e, f] = [
      matrix.a,
      matrix.b,
      matrix.c,
      matrix.d,
      matrix.e,
      matrix.f
    ];
    matrixString = [a, b, c, d, e, f].join(" ");
    //exclude non transformed elements
    if (matrixString != "1 0 0 1 0 0") {
      el.setAttribute("transform", `matrix(${matrixString})`);
      el.removeAttribute("transform-origin");
    }
  }
  return matrixString;
}


// convert fill styles to attributes
function styleToAttribute(el, attributes = ['fill', 'stroke', 'stroke-width']) {
  let types = ["path", "polygon", "polyline", "rect", "ellipse", "circle", "line", "text", "g", "svg"];
  let type = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
  if (types.indexOf(type) !== -1) {
    let style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    attributes.forEach(function(attName) {
      let value = style.getPropertyValue(attName);
      if (value !== 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
        el.setAttribute(attName, value);
      }
    })
  }
}

//convert nested svgs to groups
function nestedSvgToGroup(svg) {
  let svgSub = svg;
  if (svg.parentNode) {
    let parent = svg.parentNode.closest('svg');
    let svgSubChildren = [...svgSub.children];
    let groupMatrix = transFormToMatrix(svgSub);

    //replace nested svg with group - apply matrix
    let group = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
    group.classList.add('svgNest');
    group.setAttribute('transform', `matrix( ${groupMatrix} )`);

    //copy children to group
    svgSubChildren.forEach(function(child, i) {
      group.appendChild(child);
    })
    //remove nested svg
    svgSub.replaceWith(group);
  }
}
```

```css
svg {
  width: 80%
}
```

```html
<svg class="center" viewBox="0 0 833 396" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <style>
                @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Audiowide&amp;family=Black+Ops+One&amp;family=Faster+One&amp;family=Fugaz+One&amp;family=Racing+Sans+One&amp;display=swap");

                .fillColor {
                    fill: currentColor;
                }

                .strokeColor {
                    stroke: currentColor;
                    fill: none;
                    stroke-width: 5px;
                }

                .fillStrokeColor {
                    stroke: currentColor;
                    fill: currentColor;
                    stroke-width: 1px;
                }

                text {
                    font-family: 'Fugaz One', cursive;
                }
            </style>
            <rect id="allCarpet" x="0" y="0" width="833" height="396"></rect>
            <rect class="fillColor" id="foamCarpet" x="10" y="10" width="813" height="376" style="color:#ffd100"></rect>
            <!-- <rect class="fillColor" id="leftLogo" x="22" y="105" width="84" height="187" style="color:white" /> -->
            <text class="svg" x="580" y="345" font-size="15" id="topNickname" fill="black" textLength="70"
                lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">FLORIAN</text>
            <text class="svg" x="590" y="368" font-size="30" id="topNickname" fill="black" textLength="80"
                lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">FLORIAN</text>
            <text class="svg" x="-25" y="55" font-size="60" id="topNumber" fill="black" textLength="80"
                lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" transform="rotate(180)" transform-origin="42px 42px">00</text>
            <text class="svg" x="725" y="366" font-size="60" id="botNumber" fill="black" textLength="80"
                lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">00</text>

            <svg version="1.1" class="nested" id="Calque_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="1px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 197 100"
                style="enable-background:new 0 0 197 100;" xml:space="preserve" width="150px">
                <style type="text/css">
                    .st0 {
                        fill: #CA0D25;
                    }

                    .st1 {
                        fill: none;
                    }

                    .st2 {
                        fill: #FF0000;
                    }

                    .st3 {
                        fill: #FEFEFE;
                    }
                </style>

                <path class="st1" d="M7.2,3.8v92.5h182.7V3.8H7.2z M186.8,93.2H10.2V6.8h176.5L186.8,93.2L186.8,93.2z"
                    transform="rotate(90)" transform-origin="center"></path>
                <path class="st2" fill="red" d="M66.9,62.1v0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.3H66.9z M73.7,41.5c-5.6,0-6.9,5-6.9,9.6c0,4.6,1.3,9.5,6.9,9.5
c5.2-0.1,6.9-4.7,6.9-9.5C80.5,46.4,78.7,41.6,73.7,41.5z M43.4,53.1c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.7,0.1c-2.5,0.5-5.1,1.6-5.1,4.6
c0,3.1,2.1,3.4,4.7,3.4c0.4,0,0.7,0,1.1,0c5.2-0.5,5.7-4.4,5.7-6.1L49,51.5C47.8,52.6,45.7,52.8,43.4,53.1z M186.8,6.8v86.3H10.2
V6.8H186.8z M57.5,66.4c-1.3-1.7-0.9-3.9-0.9-6.6V44.3c0-7.6-7.8-8.4-13.3-8.4c-6.2,0.1-11.9,2.3-12.3,9.5l7.3,0.1
c0.3-2.7,2.1-4,5.1-4.1c2.7,0,5.8,0.3,5.8,4c0,2.4-2.6,2.6-5.8,2.7c-1.4,0-2.8,0.1-4.3,0.3c-4.9,0.7-9.2,2.6-9.2,9.3
c0,5.3,4.1,9.2,9.9,9.2c1.2,0,2.1,0,3.3-0.2l0.3,0c2.2-0.4,4.3-1.3,6-3.1c0,0.9,0.6,1.9,0.9,2.8L57.5,66.4L57.5,66.4z M88.7,51.3
c0-8.5-4.2-16-13.5-16c-0.5,0-1,0-1.5,0.1c-3.1,0.4-5.7,1.8-7.4,4.5h-0.1v-3.1h-6.9v37.8h7.6V62.4c1.6,2.2,4.1,3.6,6.8,4.1
c0.6,0.1,1.3,0.1,2,0.1C84.3,66.7,88.7,59.2,88.7,51.3z M106.1,35.9c-4.3,0-7.1,1.8-8.8,5.5l0-4.8h-7.1v29.8h7.6V53
c0-6.8,3.8-9.5,8.2-9.5L106.1,35.9L106.1,35.9z M116.5,36.7h-7.6v29.7h7.6V36.7z M116.5,25.4h-7.6v6.8h7.6V25.4z M126.5,25.4h-7.6
v41.1h7.6V25.4z M136.7,36.7H129v29.7h7.6V36.7z M136.7,25.4H129v6.8h7.6V25.4z M166.7,66.3c-1.3-1.7-0.9-3.9-0.9-6.6V44.2
c0-7.6-7.8-8.4-13.3-8.4c-6.2,0.1-11.9,2.3-12.3,9.5l7.3,0.1c0.3-2.7,2.1-4,5.1-4.1c2.7,0,5.8,0.3,5.8,4c0,2.4-2.6,2.6-5.8,2.7
c-1.4,0-2.8,0.1-4.3,0.3c-4.9,0.7-9.2,2.6-9.2,9.3c0,5.3,4.1,9.2,9.9,9.2c1.2,0,2.1,0,3.3-0.2l0.3,0c2.2-0.4,4.3-1.3,6-3.1
c0,0.9,0.6,1.9,0.9,2.8L166.7,66.3L166.7,66.3z M152.5,53c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.7,0.1c-2.5,0.5-5.1,1.6-5.1,4.6c0,3.1,2.1,3.4,4.7,3.4
c0.4,0,0.7,0,1.1,0c5.2-0.5,5.7-4.4,5.7-6.1l-0.1-3.7C156.9,52.5,154.8,52.7,152.5,53z" transform="rotate(90)"
                    transform-origin="center"></path>
                <path class="st3"
                    d="M129.2,25.4h7.6v6.8h-7.6V25.4z M57.7,66.4h-7.3c-0.3-0.9-0.8-1.9-0.9-2.8c-1.6,1.8-3.7,2.7-6,3.1l-0.3,0
c-1.2,0.2-2.1,0.2-3.3,0.2c-5.8,0-9.9-4-9.9-9.2c0-6.7,4.3-8.6,9.2-9.3c1.5-0.2,2.9-0.3,4.3-0.3c3.2-0.2,5.8-0.4,5.8-2.7
c0-3.7-3-4-5.8-4c-2.9,0-4.8,1.3-5.1,4.1l-7.3-0.1c0.5-7.1,6.1-9.4,12.3-9.5c5.4,0,13.3,0.8,13.3,8.4v15.5
C56.9,62.4,56.5,64.7,57.7,66.4z M49.3,55.1l-0.1-3.7c-1.2,1.1-3.3,1.3-5.6,1.6c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.7,0.1c-2.5,0.5-5.1,1.6-5.1,4.6
c0,3.1,2.1,3.4,4.7,3.4c0.4,0,0.7,0,1.1,0C48.8,60.7,49.3,56.8,49.3,55.1z M166.9,66.3h-7.3c-0.3-0.9-0.8-1.9-0.9-2.8
c-1.6,1.8-3.7,2.7-6,3.1l-0.3,0c-1.2,0.2-2.1,0.2-3.3,0.2c-5.8,0-9.9-4-9.9-9.2c0-6.7,4.3-8.6,9.2-9.3c1.5-0.2,2.9-0.3,4.3-0.3
c3.2-0.2,5.8-0.4,5.8-2.7c0-3.7-3-4-5.8-4c-2.9,0-4.8,1.3-5.1,4.1l-7.3-0.1c0.5-7.1,6.1-9.4,12.3-9.5c5.4,0,13.3,0.8,13.3,8.4v15.5
C166,62.3,165.6,64.6,166.9,66.3z M158.4,55l-0.1-3.7c-1.2,1.1-3.3,1.3-5.6,1.6c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.7,0.1c-2.5,0.5-5.1,1.6-5.1,4.6
c0,3.1,2.1,3.4,4.7,3.4c0.4,0,0.7,0,1.1,0C157.9,60.7,158.4,56.7,158.4,55z M88.9,51.2c0,8-4.4,15.4-13.1,15.4c-0.6,0-1.3,0-2-0.1
c-2.7-0.4-5.2-1.9-6.8-4.1v-0.3h-0.2c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3v12.2h-7.6V36.8h6.9v3.1h0.1c1.7-2.7,4.3-4.2,7.4-4.5
c0.5,0,1-0.1,1.5-0.1C84.8,35.2,88.9,42.8,88.9,51.2z M80.7,51c0-4.6-1.8-9.4-6.9-9.6c-5.6,0-6.9,5-6.9,9.6c0,4.6,1.3,9.5,6.9,9.5
C79.1,60.4,80.7,55.8,80.7,51z M129.2,66.4h7.6V36.7h-7.6V66.4z M119.1,66.5h7.6V25.4h-7.6V66.5z M109.1,66.4h7.6V36.7h-7.6V66.4z
M97.5,41.4l0-4.8h-7.1v29.8h7.6V53c0-6.8,3.8-9.5,8.2-9.5v-7.6C102,35.9,99.2,37.7,97.5,41.4z M109.1,32.2h7.6v-6.8h-7.6V32.2z"
                    transform="rotate(90)" transform-origin="center"></path>

            </svg>
<text class="svg" x="323" y="586" font-size="100" id="rightText" fill="black" transform="rotate(-90)" transform-origin="center" textLength="187" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">EXEMPLE</text>
<polyline class="strokeColor" id="centerPolygon" points="144,103 642,103 689,153 689,294 192,294 144,246 144,100.5" style="color:#010101;"></polyline>
<polyline class="fillStrokeColor" id="bottomPolygon" points="10,374 525,374 547,347 10,347" style="color:#009afb"></polyline>
<polyline class="fillStrokeColor" id="topPolygon" points="823,22 308,22 286,49 823,49" style="color:#009afb">
</polyline>
<polyline class="fillStrokeColor" id="littleBottomPolygon" points="10,340 553,340 560,332 10,332" style="color:#fefefe"></polyline>
<polyline class="fillStrokeColor" id="littleTopPolygon" points="823,57 280,57 273,65 823,65" style="color:#fefefe"></polyline>
</svg>

<p><button type="button" onclick="fixNestedSvgs()"> Fix nested svg</button></p>
<textarea id="svgMarkup" style="width:100%; min-height:20em"></textarea>
```

#### Drawbacks

This conversions might fail in browsers struggling with `transform-origin` (like some safari/webkit versions).

Some graphic applications might also have issues parsing inherited fill attributes like `fill:currentColor`.
The above example includes a helper `styleToAttribute()` to inline some attributes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very complete answer ! I'll come back to this problem in a few days/weeks.