# Downloading QRCode in SVG

Tags: javascript, download, save

I'm using the [EasyQRCodeJS](https://github.com/ushelp/EasyQRCodeJS) plugin but I am finding it hard to download/save the QR Code to my device in an SVG format.

Here's the code I am using. It's creating and displaying the QR Code fine displaying but the file will not open so I am doing someone incorrectly.

```js
// Options
    var options = {
        text: "https://github.com/ushelp/EasyQRCodeJS",
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    colorDark : "#000000",
    colorLight : "#ffffff",
    correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H, // L, M, Q, H
    logo: "https://assets.website-files.com/6130bd1fcd31de20d9599493/627b6e7e75f1c5ef5f36ff22_customjava.svg", 
    logoWidth: 50, // fixed logo width. default is width/3.5
    logoHeight: 50, // fixed logo height. default is heigth/3.5,
    crossOrigin : 'anonymous',
    quietZone: 0,
    quietZoneColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    drawer: 'svg',
    logoBackgroundColor: '#fffff', // Logo backgroud color, Invalid when logBgTransparent is true; default is '#ffffff'
    logoBackgroundTransparent: false, // Whether use transparent image, default is false
    };
    
    // Create QRCode Object
    new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), options);
  







function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
/* alert(QRCode); */
    var text = QRCode;
    var filename = "qrcode.svg";
    
    download(filename, text);
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/easyqrcodejs@4.4.12/dist/easy.qrcode.min.js"></script>
<div id="qrcode"></div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Download" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var text = QRCode;` won't return your svg code but the QRCode object.

Add a element variable and fetch it's `innerHTML` like so:

```
var text = qrcodeEl.innerHTML;
```

#### Example

```js
// Options
var options = {
  text: "https://github.com/ushelp/EasyQRCodeJS",
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  colorDark: "#000000",
  colorLight: "#ffffff",
  correctLevel: QRCode.CorrectLevel.H, // L, M, Q, H
  logo: "https://assets.website-files.com/6130bd1fcd31de20d9599493/627b6e7e75f1c5ef5f36ff22_customjava.svg",
  logoWidth: 50, // fixed logo width. default is width/3.5
  logoHeight: 50, // fixed logo height. default is heigth/3.5,
  crossOrigin: "anonymous",
  quietZone: 0,
  quietZoneColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  drawer: "svg",
  logoBackgroundColor: "#fffff", // Logo backgroud color, Invalid when logBgTransparent is true; default is '#ffffff'
  logoBackgroundTransparent: false // Whether use transparent image, default is false
};

const qrcodeEl = document.getElementById("qrcode");
const QR = new QRCode(qrcodeEl, options);

function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement("a");
  console.log(text);
  element.setAttribute(
    "href",
    "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(text)
  );
  element.setAttribute("download", filename);
  element.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.click();
  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener(
  "click",
  function() {
    /* alert(QRCode); */
    var text = qrcodeEl.innerHTML;
    console.log(text)
    var filename = "qrcode.svg";
    download(filename, text);
  },
  false
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/easyqrcodejs@4.4.12/dist/easy.qrcode.min.js"></script>
<div id="qrcode"></div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Download" />
```

Download won't work in SO snippet due to security settings.

#### Embed logo svg

This will only work if you're using a data URL for your logo.
External logo svgs will most likely not work due to CORS policies.
If logos are on the same domain you might use an ajax `fetch()` to retrieve all data.
I've converted the logo with [Yoksel's URL-encoder for svg](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/).

```js
// getTransformToElement polyfill
SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement =
  SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement ||
  function (toElement) {
    return toElement.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(this.getScreenCTM());
  };

// Options
var options = {
  text: "https://github.com/ushelp/EasyQRCodeJS",
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  colorDark: "#000000",
  colorLight: "#ffffff",
  correctLevel: QRCode.CorrectLevel.H, // L, M, Q, H
  logo:
    "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='441' height='352' viewBox='0 0 441 352' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' clip-rule='evenodd' d='M26.0869 35.7268V26.0865H35.8516V7.65674H7.65723V35.7268H26.0869ZM26.0869 58.8637H7.65723V78.1444H26.0869V58.8637ZM26.0869 101.281H7.65723V120.562H26.0869V101.281ZM26.0869 143.699H7.65723V162.98H26.0869V143.699ZM26.0869 186.117H7.65723V205.397H26.0869V186.117ZM26.0869 228.534H7.65723V247.815H26.0869V228.534ZM26.0869 270.952H7.65723V290.232H26.0869V270.952ZM26.0869 313.369H7.65723V341.439H35.8516V323.01H26.0869V313.369ZM59.2869 323.01V341.439H78.8162V323.01H59.2869ZM102.251 323.01V341.439H121.781V323.01H102.251ZM145.216 323.01V341.439H164.745V323.01H145.216ZM188.181 323.01V341.439H207.71V323.01H188.181ZM231.145 323.01V341.439H250.675V323.01H231.145ZM274.11 323.01V341.439H293.639V323.01H274.11ZM317.074 323.01V341.439H336.604V323.01H317.074ZM360.039 323.01V341.439H379.568V323.01H360.039ZM403.004 323.01V341.439H431.198V313.369H412.768V323.01H403.004ZM412.768 290.232H431.198V270.952H412.768V290.232ZM412.768 247.815H431.198V228.534H412.768V247.815ZM412.768 205.397H431.198V186.117H412.768V205.397ZM412.768 162.98H431.198V143.699H412.768V162.98ZM412.768 120.562H431.198V101.281H412.768V120.562ZM412.768 78.1445H431.198V58.8638H412.768V78.1445ZM412.768 35.7269V26.0865H403.004V7.65674H431.198V35.7269H412.768ZM379.568 26.0865V7.65674H360.039V26.0865H379.568ZM336.604 26.0865V7.65674H317.074V26.0865H336.604ZM293.639 26.0865V7.65674H274.11V26.0865H293.639ZM250.675 26.0865V7.65674H231.145V26.0865H250.675ZM207.71 26.0865V7.65674H188.181V26.0865H207.71ZM164.745 26.0865V7.65674H145.216V26.0865H164.745ZM121.781 26.0865V7.65674H102.251V26.0865H121.781ZM78.8162 26.0865V7.65674H59.2869V26.0865H78.8162Z' fill='%235836F5'/%3E%3Crect x='80.377' y='76.5498' width='274.398' height='196.547' fill='%235836F5'/%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' clip-rule='evenodd' d='M167.67 122.48L177.04 133.328L133.073 171.309L176.976 208.345L167.734 219.301L110.996 171.438L167.67 122.48Z' fill='white'/%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' clip-rule='evenodd' d='M268.656 122.48L259.286 133.328L303.253 171.309L259.35 208.345L268.593 219.301L325.33 171.438L268.656 122.48Z' fill='white'/%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' clip-rule='evenodd' d='M187.544 234.91L237.714 103.343L251.107 108.45L200.937 240.018L187.544 234.91Z' fill='%23C9BFFC'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='419.042' cy='20.9894' r='20.9894' fill='%235836F5'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='20.9894' cy='20.9894' r='20.9894' fill='%235836F5'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='419.042' cy='331.011' r='20.9894' fill='%235836F5'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='20.9894' cy='331.011' r='20.9894' fill='%235836F5'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A",
  logoWidth: 50, // fixed logo width. default is width/3.5
  logoHeight: 50, // fixed logo height. default is heigth/3.5,
  crossOrigin: "anonymous",
  quietZone: 0,
  quietZoneColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  drawer: "svg",
  logoBackgroundColor: "#fffff", // Logo backgroud color, Invalid when logBgTransparent is true; default is '#ffffff'
  logoBackgroundTransparent: false // Whether use transparent image, default is false
};

const qrcodeEl = document.getElementById("qrcode");
new QRCode(qrcodeEl, options);


function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement("a");
  console.log(text);
  element.setAttribute(
    "href",
    "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(text)
  );
  element.setAttribute("download", filename);
  element.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.click();
  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener(
  "click",
  function () {
    //embed logo
    embedLogo();
    var text = qrcodeEl.innerHTML;
    console.log(text);
    var filename = "qrcode.svg";
    download(filename, text);
  },
  false
);

function embedLogo() {
  let qrSVG = document.querySelector("svg");
  let logo = qrSVG.querySelector("image");
  let imgTrans = logo.getAttribute("transform");
  let imgWidth = logo.getAttribute("width");
  let imgHeight = logo.getAttribute("height");
  //convert data url to svg
  let logoSrc = logo
    .getAttribute("xlink:href")
    .replaceAll("data:image/svg+xml,", "")
    .replaceAll("%3C", "<")
    .replaceAll("%3E", ">")
    .replaceAll("%3C/", "/")
    .replaceAll("%0A", "\n")
    .replaceAll("%23", "#");

  // append logo svg
  let logogroup = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
  qrSVG.appendChild(logogroup);
  logogroup.innerHTML = logoSrc;
  let logoEmbedded = logogroup.querySelector("svg");
  logoEmbedded.setAttribute("width", imgWidth);
  logoEmbedded.setAttribute("height", imgHeight);
  logogroup.setAttribute("transform", imgTrans);

  //convert nesest logo svg to group
  nestedSvgToGroup(logoEmbedded);
  logogroup.removeAttribute("transform");
  logo.remove();
}

/**
 * convert nested svg to embedded g
 */
function nestedSvgToGroup(svg, groupMatrix = 0) {
  let svgSub = svg;
  if (svg.parentNode) {
    let parent = svg.parentNode.closest("svg");
    let svgSubChildren = [...svgSub.children];
    groupMatrix = groupMatrix ? groupMatrix : transFormToMatrix(svgSub);

    //replace nested svg with group - apply matrix
    let group = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
    group.classList.add("svgNest");
    group.setAttribute("transform", `matrix( ${groupMatrix} )`);

    //copy children to group
    svgSubChildren.forEach(function (child, i) {
      group.appendChild(child);
    });
    //remove nested svg
    svgSub.replaceWith(group);
  }
}

function transFormToMatrix(el) {
  let type = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
  let matrixString = "";
  let types = [
    "path",
    "polygon",
    "polyline",
    "rect",
    "ellipse",
    "circle",
    "line",
    "text",
    "g",
    "svg"
  ];
  if (types.indexOf(type) !== -1) {
    // get el matrix
    let matrix = el.getTransformToElement(el.parentNode.closest("svg"));
    let [a, b, c, d, e, f] = [
      matrix.a,
      matrix.b,
      matrix.c,
      matrix.d,
      matrix.e,
      matrix.f
    ];
    matrixString = [a, b, c, d, e, f].join(" ");
    //exclude non transformed elements
    if (matrixString != "1 0 0 1 0 0") {
      el.setAttribute("transform", `matrix(${matrixString})`);
      el.removeAttribute("transform-origin");
    }
  }
  return matrixString;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/easyqrcodejs@4.4.12/dist/easy.qrcode.min.js"></script>
<div id="qrcode"></div>
<p><input type="button" id="button" value="Download" /></p>
```

#### How it works

1. convert your logo to a data url and add it to your option
2. `embedLogo()` helper will add a nested svg to the parent QRcode svg
3. `nestedSvgToGroup()` will translate transformations to a `matrix()`
4. `<image>` is removed

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/ZExyJYa)
[See also: Issues with conversion of svg element to .svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73024793/issues-with-conversion-of-svg-element-to-svg/73057219#73057219)

Comment: I was a bit premature marking the question as answered. Although the image does now download as an SVG file, the center image isn't correct and is just a coloured square.

Comment: That's because your logo is an extenal reference. It will be displayed in browsers but won't work as a selft contained svg file. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Juan-man: I#ve added a new example. However it requires to convert your logo to a data URL